Reducing the barcode128 size when it has 44 chars
I am developing a label with a somewhat peculiar characteristic. The label needs to have dimensions of 10x15cm, 8 dpmm (203 dpi) and include a barcode with 44 characters. When inserting the barcode, the equipment responsible for reading it cannot read it due to the spacing between the barcode bars.
When increasing the size, the barcode ends up exceeding the label's margin limit. I would like your support to understand if there is anything else I can do to correct this issue.
I will leave a link here to exemplify the problem I am experiencing.
I changed the code considering to increase the value to 3, but the label exceeded the margin:
^XA ^FX Barcode ^FO195,10 ^BY3,2,90 ^BCR ^FDGWHN6TJKJKN7GUDIXHEU86V3B7L40S2GFAMPJTNR ^FS ^XZ

44 alphanumeric characters is going to be a long barcode - not much you can do about that.  Can you change to a 2d barcode such as rectangular datamatrix?  That will give you a lot more data in the same space.
